# Switching flight mode programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way switch on/off flight mode programmatically in Windows Phone 7.5. What I want to do is create background task which will be check time and switch on/off flight mode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this functionality is not available.

It was a design principle behind the platform that applications should not be able to do things without the user knowing it.
If such functionality was available then it would be possible for an app (either deliberately or accidentally-though a bug) to get the devices state in a setting other than what they user may expect. In such a scenario users will typically blaim the phone/platform for what has happened, not a misbehaving application.

Comment: Hmmmm, so bad. So if I want to use it for personal purposes f.e after 8 PM switch on flight mode it would be impossible. Maybe there is some workaround or system/dll hack?

Comment: @Arterius No work around. Any backdoor way of implementing such functionlaity would break the intention behind not providing an API for this. If you need a device which can run apps which have the ability to enable and disable flight mode, WP7 is not it.

Answer (score 4):

Though you cannot programatically do it (as others have mentioned), you can send the user directly to the proper page in the settings panel and allow them to do it. Here's an example of using the ConnectionsSettingsTask:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394011(v=VS.92).aspx

You would want to set the ConnectionSettingsType property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.connectionsettingstask.connectionsettingstype(v=VS.92).aspx

To 'AirplaneMode'.